# Numpy 2d histogram not summing to 1

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I think I'm misunderstanding Numpy's histogram2d `range` and `bin` arguments.

Here's a example of it working how I'd expect:

```
d, x_r, y_r = np.histogram2d(
    [0, 1, 3], 
    [0, 1, 3], 
    bins=[3, 3], 
    range=[[0, 3], [0, 3]], 
    normed=True)

d
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333]])
np.sum(d)
1.0
```

And here's where things start to fall apart for me (increasing bin count):

```
d, x_r, y_r = np.histogram2d(
    [0, 1, 3], 
    [0, 1, 3], 
    bins=[3, 6], 
    range=[[0, 3], [0, 3]], 
    normed=True)
d
array([[ 0.66666667,  0.,  0.        ,  0.,  0., 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.,  0.66666667,  0.,  0., 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.,  0.        ,  0.,  0., 0.66666667]])
np.sum(d)
2.0
```

I would have expected:

```
d
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.,  0.        ,  0.,  0., 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.,  0.33333333,  0.,  0., 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.,  0.        ,  0.,  0., 0.33333333]])
```

Would appreciate any help on understanding this and getting the result I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)? Look at normed vs. density and their warnings.

Comment: @sascha I did indeed read the docs. I'll reread those sections and play around with them. I'm not a statistician so bit hard for me to understand them. Also I'm using the 2d function which doesn't have a density argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normed arg in [np.histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) normalizes as follows

```
bin_count / sample_count / bin_area
```

These take a while to understand, and the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1011) is not written very well in my opinion (poorly chosen variable names)

- `bin_count` is is the value in the histogram bin
- `sample_count` is the total sum of all bin_counts
- `bin_area` is the area of the particular bin

We can define the above 3 variables in both cases *without using the normed arg*, and see whats going on:

## Case 1

```
bin_count, binsx, binsy = np.histogram2d( [0,1,3], [0,1,3], 
    bins=[3,3], range=[[0,3],[0,3]], normed=False)
```

If you look at `binsx` and `binsy` you will see the area of each bin is 1

```
print(binsx, binsy)
#In [54]: print (binsx, binsy)
#(array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]))
```

Therefore we let `bin_area=1` and the 2D histogram **normalized** looks like

```
bin_count / bin_count.sum() / bin_area

#array([[ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       #[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ],
       #[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333]])
```

## Case 2

```
bin_count, binsx, binsy = np.histogram2d( [0,1,3], [0,1,3], 
    bins=[3,6], range=[[0,3],[0,3]], normed=False)
print(binsx, binsy)
#(array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ]))
```

Now you can see your `bin_area` has decreased by a factor of 2 (because you increased the number of y-bins by a factor of 2)

Hence , we let `bin_area=.5`, and the **normalized** hist looks like

```
bin_count / bin_count.sum() / bin_area

#array([[ 0.66666667,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
#         0.        ],
#       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.66666667,  0.        ,  0.        ,
#         0.        ],
#       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
#         0.66666667]])
```

## General Case

In general you can have bins of variable sizes, hence bin_area might be a variable. Consider some non-even bins:

```
bin_count, binsx, binsy = np.histogram2d( [0,1,3], [0,1,3], 
    bins=([0.,1.5,3.],[0, .6, 1.7,3.]), 
    range=[[0,3],[0,3]], normed=False)
```

In this case, calculate the area of each bin explicitly:

```
bin_area = np.array( [ [(x1 -x0)* (y1-y0) 
    for y1,y0 in zip(binsy[1:], binsy[:-1])] 
        for x1,x0 in zip(binsx[1:], binsx[:-1]) ] )

print(bin_area)
#array([[ 0.9 ,  1.65,  1.95],
#       [ 0.9 ,  1.65,  1.95]])

bin_count / bin_count.sum() / bin_area
#array([[ 0.37037037,  0.2020202 ,  0.        ],
#       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.17094017]])
```

Indeed, if we set the normed arg to True

```
normed_bin_count, binsx, binsy = np.histogram2d( [0,1,3], [0,1,3], 
    bins=([0.,1.5,3.],[0, .6, 1.7,3.]), 
    range=[[0,3],[0,3]], normed=True)
print(normed_bin_count)
#array([[ 0.37037037,  0.2020202 ,  0.        ],
#       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.17094017]])
```

Comment: great, thank you. So I need to just multiply the x and y by the bin size to get back to what I expect.

Comment: I think it's easy to understand if you think that `bin_count` is the number of samples in a bin and `sample_count` is the total number of samples.

Comment: @freebie If you want relative proportions use `normed=False` then divide each bin count by the number of samples. That woudn't be a normed histogram.

Comment: @Goyo Oh, right. Cheers. I need to go brush up on my statistics, clearly